# How to label a multi-line equation?

Tags: equations, formatting, line-breaking, labels, multline

I have a a multi-line equation, `e_1 = e_2 = ... = e_n`. Each of the expressions `e_i` is quite long. So long, in fact, that using the `align` environment results in some of the equations intruding into the right-hand margin, and even beyond the page. Using the `multline` environment solves these issues, however this causes another problem. With the `align` environment I am able to label each of the equations, and reference them further down the document; however, with the `multline` environment, the following error message is issued:

```
Package amsmath Error: Multiple \label's: label '...' will be lost.
```

How can I label the lines of a `multline` environment? Alternatively, is there another way to achieve the following goals simultaneously:

1. Arranging the multi-line equation one equation per line.
2. Making sure none of the equations oversteps the margins.
3. Labeling each of the equations (or, more precisely, a selection of the equations), so they can be referenced.

---

Here's an example document that can be used for experimentation purposes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\sup_{\mathbf{N}}V_{\mathbf{N}, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(m+_{\mathbf{M}}n)\rangle &\geq_{\mathbf{N}}\sup_{\mathbf{N}}V_{\mathbf{N}, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(m) +_{\mathbf{R}^{(S)}_{\mathbf{N}, \varphi}} S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(n) \rangle\label{eq:1}\\
&= \sup_{\mathbf{N}}\left(V_{\mathbf{N}, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(m)\rangle +_{\mathbf{R}^{(S)}_{\mathbf{N}, \varphi}} V_{\mathbf{N}, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(n) \rangle\right)\label{eq:2}\\
&\geq_{\mathbf{N}} \sup_{\mathbf{N}}\left(V_{\mathbf{N}, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(m)\rangle\right) +_{\mathbf{N}} \sup_{\mathbf{N}}\left(V_{\mathbf{N}, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(n) \rangle\right),\label{eq:3}
\end{align}

Referencing eq.~\ref{eq:1}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2599564/how-to-label-each-equation-in-align-environment

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: A quick reading of my post will reveal that I have already tried this solution, and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Probably `align` with nested `multlined` (needs `mathtools`). You might make up an example so it would be easier to play with it and give better advice.

Comment: @egreg: I've added an example, as per your request.

Comment: @egreg: OK, I've inserted my actual code.

Comment: 1. I just browsed the site on my way from the car park to the office and wanted to give a helping hand. 2. Two of your last two questions were duplicates and so I did not very much trust your research skills :).

Comment: *Two of your last four

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no other sensible way than as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\bvar}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\bM}{\bvar{M}}
\newcommand{\bN}{\bvar{N}}
\newcommand{\bR}{\bvar{R}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\sup_{\bN}V_{\bN, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\bM, S, \bN, \varphi}(m+_{\bM}n)\rangle
\notag \\
&\qquad\geq_{\bN}\sup_{\bN}
  V_{\bN, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\bM, S, \bN, \varphi}(m)
  +_{\bR^{(S)}_{\bN, \varphi}} S_{\bM, S, \bN, \varphi}(n) \rangle
\label{eq:1}\\
&\qquad= \sup_{\bN}
  \bigl(V_{\bN, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\bM, S, \bN, \varphi}(m)\rangle
  +_{\bR^{(S)}_{\bN, \varphi}} V_{\bN, S, \varphi}
    \langle S_{\bM, S, \bN, \varphi}(n) \rangle
  \bigr)
\label{eq:2}\\
&\qquad\geq_{\bN} \sup_{\bN}
  \bigl(V_{\bN, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\bM, S, \bN, \varphi}(m)\rangle)
  +_{\bN} \sup_{\bN}(V_{\bN, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\bM, S, \bN, \varphi}(n) \rangle
  \bigr),
\label{eq:3}
\end{align}
Referencing eq.~\ref{eq:1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ...or `\MoveEqLeft` from `mathtools`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of multine, try using the `\subequations` environnement

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
e_1 = ... \\
e_2 = ... \\
... \\
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

With that solution, each e_i will be numbered `(x.i)`

For equation size, you would certainly have to play with the font size (a great way to do that is to use `fontspec` since it enables to adjust size precisely.

Edit :

Reading your comment, you can also use the `\split{}`environment which is like this :

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
e_1 = x +4 ... 5 +6 \\
= hello \\
... \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

This one allows you to do linebreaks in equations in places of your choice without changing the numbering.

Edit 2 :

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{subequations*}
equ1 \\
equ2\\
\end{subequations*}
\end{equation}
```

Should allow to have labels on subequations without any tag inside a numbered equation.

Comment: Thanks, but (a) I'd rather use the normal numbering schema, since there's nothing special about this set of equations that merits a change in numbering schema. (b) As I mentioned, the `align` environment causes some of my equations to spill beyond the size of the page. I'd rather not shrink the font size, because that would make a complicated expression even harder to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, I believe the `split` environment suffers from the same disadvantage as the `multline` environment in that it's tricky (impossible?) to label the different lines separately.

Comment: You can try nesting a `subequations*`in an `equation` environment. I think that way you can still have labels but the subequation numbers won't show. This is compatible with `split` in case of very very long equation.

Comment: +1 Never used subequations before.

Answer (score 2):

I propose this, using `\mathlap` from `mathtools` and  an `\intertext` for the beginning of the equations. I alse suggest using `cleveref` for simpler typing of equations references:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\intertext[0ex]{$\displaystyle \sup_{\mathbf{N}}\mathrlap{V_{\mathbf{N}, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(m +_{\mathbf{M}}n) \rangle} $}
&{}\geq_{\mathbf{N}}\sup_{\mathbf{N}}V_{\mathbf{N}, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(m) +_{\mathbf{R}^{(S)}_{\mathbf{N}, \varphi}} S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(n) \rangle\label{eq:1}\\
&= \sup_{\mathbf{N}}\left(V_{\mathbf{N}, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(m)\rangle +_{\mathbf{R}^{(S)}_{\mathbf{N}, \varphi}} V_{\mathbf{N}, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(n) \rangle\right)\label{eq:2}\\
&\geq_{\mathbf{N}} \sup_{\mathbf{N}}\left(V_{\mathbf{N}, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(m)\rangle\right) +_{\mathbf{N}} \sup_{\mathbf{N}}\left(V_{\mathbf{N}, S, \varphi}\langle S_{\mathbf{M}, S, \mathbf{N}, \varphi}(n) \rangle\right),\label{eq:3}
\end{align}

Referencing \cref{eq:1}.

\end{document}
```

[image]